# How to add a 'Limit Selection to view shortcut' for edit mode?

Tags: mesh, 3d-view, edit-mode

Could anyone suggest how to add a shortcut for limit selection to visible toggle in edit mode? I am not able to find this in the input section of user-preference.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Z is *not* normally assigned to 'Limit selection to visible'. Without pie menus activated it switches between 'Wire' and 'Solid' mode.

Comment: You are right. I got confused as in limit selection to visible toggle also the wireframe is seen and in wireframe mode the backfacing polygons can be selected. Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected the question.